# Debug Object Naming and Directx11

Tags: c++, visual-c++, direct3d

Is PIX required to give objects debug names? I have tried to give them names with the following code:

```
ID3D11Buffer * vertex_buffer;
...
const char c_szName[] = "vertex_buffer";
vertex_buffer->SetPrivateData( WKPDID_D3DDebugObjectName, sizeof( c_szName ) - 1, c_szName );
```

But the memory leak warnings I get when I don't release the vertex_buffer still show Name="unnamed".

Comment: The leak warnings are not generated by PIX, but by the Direct3D 11 SDK Debug Layer. It should respect names set this way, but are you getting any other warnings from the debug layer? Presumably you did create the device with the DEBUG flag, correct?